# How can create a email alert for windows events with id 0 using the message as filter

Tags: windows, powershell, events, event-log

I have event which is with event id =0, thus makes create the email alert with event id
not feasible, how can I create email alert using the message content (in Eventdata/data attributes)?
can use PowerShell or other method?

```
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
        <Provider Name="Test Portal"/>
        <EventID Qualifiers="0">0</EventID>
        <Level>2</Level>
        <Task>0</Task>
        <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
        <TimeCreated SystemTime="2023-02-03"/>
        <EventRecordID>336</EventRecordID>
        <Channel>Application</Channel>
        <Computer></Computer>
        <Security/>
    </System>
    <EventData>
        <Data>Message: Your Service is not available.</Data>
    </EventData>
</Event>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use PowerShell to find and parse the Windows Eventlog like below.
In this case, it will look for events in the 'Application' log with an ID of 0

For demo I have limited the search to a maximum of 50 items, but you can set your own value of course.

```
$result = Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{LogName='Application';ID=0} -MaxEvents 50 | ForEach-Object {
    # convert the event to XML and grab the Event node
    $eventXml = ([xml]$_.ToXml()).Event
    # output the values from the XML representation
    [PsCustomObject]@{
        Provider = $eventXml.System.Provider.Name
        Message  = $eventXml.EventData.Data  #.'#text'
        Date     = [DateTime]$eventXml.System.TimeCreated.SystemTime
    }
}
```

Now in variable `$result` you have objects you can use in your email.
When output on screen you will see something like

```
$result | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

```
Provider         Message                                   Date             
--------         -------                                   ----             
edgeupdate       Service stopped                           4-3-2023 11:38:52
gupdate          Service stopped                           4-3-2023 11:38:32
Test Portal      Message: Your Service is not available.   4-3-2023 11:38:32
```

Comment: Thanks.  Can I get the event that only have message "Message: Your Service is not available."? How can I do that?

Comment: @want_to_be_calm Sure, just filter `$result | Where-Object { $_.Message -like 'Message: * is not available*' }`. BTW, if you feel this answer solved your problem, please accept it. In the [tour] you can see how this works.

Comment: Thanks. What I want is just to receive one email instantly whenever this message happened in event. I do not not want to filter all the event to get the list. Is that possible to  just let the powershell just send one email when this event happened?